# Tips about a good class-structure for website? (php)

Tags: php, class

I'm creating a kind of massive network for users to register and login. I want to try using classes, but I've never used them (expect some mysql-wrappers etc). Could you provide some tips and sample-structure for my project?

The idea is to simply have a index.php, which prints the whole page and does all the action. Index.php calls functions from classes inside other files.

I need:

- user-class for checking if logged in and retrieving user-info
- different kind of "page"-classes for functions needed in those pages

I'm not asking for full code, but just a start. I don't know, how to use `public function`s or anything like that. How to wrap these classes to work together? So no functions, just the structure!

Martti Laine

Comment: Can you explain your rationale behind not using a framework, like Cake, Zend etc.?

Comment: I don't know if frameworks fit my needs. It's always nicer to create everything by yourself.

Comment: No it is not. It is more error prone especially if you are inexperienced. If you use a framework you have a solid basis. And even more especially if you want to create a "massive" productive application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for the first part, I'll give you hint on using the index for everything. I use a switch statement that simply calls out everything, like so:

```
<?php


switch($_REQUEST['mode']){

    case 'create':
        $ourhtml = $object->do_create();
    break;

    case 'read':
        $ourhtml = $object->do_read();
    break;

    case 'update':
        $ourhtml = $object->do_update();
    break;

    case 'delete':
        $ourhtml = $object->do_delete();
    break;

    default:

    $ourhtml = "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"> 
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mode\" value=\"create\">
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"create new\">
    </form>";

    <?php

    break;

    }

    echo $ourhtml;

?>
```

This code by itself does nothing, but it gives you a general idea of how you can switch between many different "pages" using just index. Adding a new page is as simple as adding another case to your switch statement.

As far as structure goes, I would really recommend you do some reading on MVC. It might seem complicated at first, but once you get the hang of it, it will save you a lot of time and trouble. Here are some good reads on it:

http://nemetral.net/2008/07/31/a-gentle-introduction-to-mvc-part-1/

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Also, for general class structure, nothing beats php.net's explanation of it:

[Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I heard that using only one single class for whole site is not good. Is this true?

Comment: You don't want to use a single class for the whole site, my code was just for illustration purposes. Generally my index file interacts with a single controller object, but there are many classes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Read about [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in general.
2. Read the manual about [OOP in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

You really should get your head around OOP.
Afterwards read about some design patterns that are commonly used in web applications, e.g.

- [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC)
- [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) pattern (← this is basically what you want achieve with your `index.php`)

Have a look or even use the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) or any other [framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why). You can learn the most if you look at other sourcecode. But in order to understand the code, you have to understand OOP.

---

**If it is not for learning purpose I wouldn't write such an application from scratch.**
Use a framework that already implements the typical patterns and tools to help you (especially as you are not used to OOP, but nevertheless you have to learn OOP).

Comment: Yea, the idea is to get some experience on classes. That's why I'm trying to create it myself.

Comment: @Martti Laine: It is still good the read the frameworks source code.

Comment: That may be true. I'll check 'em.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look over some free resources. This will be more helpful than trying to explain everything in a post:

- http://www.spoono.com/php/tutorials/tutorial.php?id=27
- http://www.php-editors.com/articles/simple_php_classes.php